# How do I add a UITextfield that requests a webpage

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am working on turning https://ppyazi.com/viral into a web view to submit to the Apple App Store. I am trying to make a `UITextfield` that when someone enters their twitter username, it requests https://ppyazi.com/viral/home.php?username=(UsernameHere). Basically, I want the `UITextfield` to function the same way as the login section on https://ppyazi.com/viral.

Comment: Why cant you take the text property of the textfield on the button tap event, and append it with your url string. where are you facing the issue in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add a `UIButton` with action requesting `ppyazi url` or you can declare :

```
textview.delegate = self;
```

and implement UITextViewDelegate

and use :

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
//Do your Code to request URL
return true
}
```